# How to addTarget to UIButton without sender

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, selector, sender

I have a function...

```
func MyFunc (_ sender: AnyObject) { 
    let n = sender.tag! //do stuff with 'n'
}
```

which I connect when creating my NewButton...

```
NewButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(Main.MyFunc(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

---

I'd like to call `MyFunc` in other areas of my code without a sender. Is it possible to .addTarget to a Button without using sender?

Such as....

```
NewButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(Main.MyFunc(n: 5)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

and...

```
func MyFunc (n: Int) {
    //do stuff with 'n'
}
```

---

I know one solution would be a routing function like...

```
func router (_ sender: AnyObject) {
    MyFunc(n: sender.tag!)
}
```

But I'm wondering if there's a more elegant way.

Comment: What? Why not just pass the button as the parameter? And yes, you can create a target without a sender. Just don't put the argument. If by connect, you mean via storyboards then I think it must have a sender..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the function takes a sender of type `AnyObject` you can use any object as an argument to the function. You will then just need to conditionally cast it to the type you want.

```
let button = UIButton()
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(touched(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

touched(1 as AnyObject) // Works

@objc func touched(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    if let casted = sender as? Int {
        // Do something with casted as an Int
    } else if let casted = sender as? UIButton {
        // do something with casted.tag
    }
}
```